# Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions when use jest in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I'm junior in java script and reactJs and writing a simple project.
I install jest package with yarn to my project with this command line:

```
yarn add jest
```

when i want run my test with command line i can't and i have this error:

```
Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "expensify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "mahdi",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack --watch",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dates": "^21.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "validator": "^11.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "dev-server": "^0.1.0",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

help to solve this error. thanks guys